# finding all keys that map to a value in javascript. And efficient alternatives

Tags: javascript, object, search, types, key

I'm working on an application in javascript where each user is in a room. No two users share the same name and no two rooms share the same name. Currently I have it set up like this:

```
var userroommap = {
  username: "room",
  username2: "room",
  username3: "room2"
}
```

getting the room a user is in is as simple as

```
userroommap["user"]
```

but in order to get all users which are present in a room I would have to iterate over the entire userroommap like so:

```
for (var x in userroommap) {
  if (userroommap[x] == "room")
    //user x is present in room 
  }
}
```

In my application I must know which users are in which rooms very often so I am considering using another object to hold all users in a room, something like:

```
var roomusermap = {
  room:["username", "username2"],
  room2:["username3"]
}
```

Adding users to the room is trivial because all you have to do is append to an array, however removing a username from a room requires iterating over the array and becomes a decent operation. This already is a decent solution to my problem, but I became curious if there was a better solution. So: is there a better way to (i) store the roomusermap, perhaps without arrays? or, alternatively (ii) find all users in a room?

Comment: What's the problem with using the object? Are you seeing **real** performance issues?

Comment: i guess I am just curious if there is some way to do value: key that I didn't list. However your comment made me realize it is kind of a useless question :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data-structure described in the previous answer is called a **BiMap**.

A BiMap ideally provides equivalent performance for `value: keys` lookup operations as for `key: values` lookups. It is typically implemented by internally managing two separate maps (one with a *forward-mapping* `{key:values}` and one with a *reverse-mapping* `{value:keys}`).

Here's an existing implementation to use if you're not rolling your own.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/bimap

Answer (score 1):

Unless you've identified a genuine, real-world performance problem, I'd stick with the simple solution.

That said, a few thoughts for you:

- All modern JavaScript engines give you the `Object.keys` function, which returns an array of an object's *own enumerable* properties. This may be more efficient than your `for-in` loop for two reasons:

  1. It's happening within the engine's code, which lets the engine optimize
  2. `for-in` looks for enumerable properties in prototype objects, whereas `Object.keys` knows it's only supposed to look in that specific object
- Your `roomusermap` can contain maps per room, it doesn't need to use arrays.

  ```
  var roomusermap = {
      room: {
          username: user,
          username2: user2
      },
      room2: {
          username3: user3
      }
  };
  ```

  Adding a user to a room becomes:

  ```
  userroommap[username] = roomname;
  roomusermap[roomname][username] = user;
  ```

  Removing a user is:

  ```
  delete userroommap[username];
  delete roomusermap[roomname][username];
  ```
- If you're seeing performance problems with those map objects, something to keep in mind is that removing a property from an object (`delete`) puts the object into "dictionary mode" on several JavaScript engines (having previously been in a more optimized state), significantly impacting the time required to look up properties on that object.

  So in the very hypothetical case where the property lookup performance starts to be an issue, you could consider storing `undefined` rather than deleting the property. E.g., instead of:

  ```
  delete userroommap[username];
  delete roomusermap[roomname][username];
  ```

  you'd do

  ```
  userroommap[username] = undefined;
  roomusermap[roomname][username] = undefined;
  ```

  However, you'd have to adjust your checks for whether a user is in a room, and you couldn't use `Object.keys` (on its own) to get the list anymore since you have to weed out the properties with the value `undefined`. You could use `Object.keys` with `filter`:

  ```
  var map = roomusermap[roomname];
  var users = Object.keys(map).filter(function(username) {
      return map[username] !== undefined;
  });
  ```

  So you'd *really* want to do that only if you've identifed a *genuine problem* caused by objects going into dictionary mode.

Comment: Maybe not such a useless question, this is helpful, thank you.